# Call to getBindingContext fails for a named model

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem with a `getBinding` using UI5.
I can bind a List to a JSON Model like so.

```js
var sServiceUrl = "http://localhost:56154/api/store";
var myModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
myModel.loadData(sServiceUrl);
oView.setModel(myModel);
```

Alternatively, I can specify a 'name' for the model by changing the last line as follows:

```js
oView.setModel(myModel, "foo");
```

Both work fine! I reference them (in my XML views) as below (items attribute refers).

**Without** a named reference to the mode:

```xml
<List items="{/}">
```

**With** a named reference to the mode:

```js
<List items="{foo>/}">
```

**Problem Statement**

This command fails when I attempt to retrieve the binding context (in the case of the named model. the exact issue is getBindingContext() is undefined).

```js
var sPath = oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext();
```

Can anyone help me understand what to do - I presume the '>' in may cause the problem but given naming a model is standard/good practice. I am not sure why this should cause the function to fail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getBindingContext() returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913868/getbindingcontext-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the model name to the method:

```
oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext("foo")
```